# Is my proof ok or not? (Theorem 7' in "Introduction to Set Theory and General Topology" by Kazuo Matsuzaka)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Theorem 7:
> Let $S$ be a non-empty set.
> Let $i:2^S\to2^S$ be a function which satisfies the following conditions:
> (1) $i(S)=S$.
> (2) $i(M)\subset M$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> (3) $i(M\cap N)=i(M)\cap i(N)$ for any $M,N\in 2^S$.
> (4) $i(i(M))=i(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> Then, there exists a unique topological space $(S,\mathcal{O})$ such that $\operatorname{Int}M=i(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.

> Lemma 1:
> Let $(S,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space.
> Let $M\subset S$.
> Then, $\overline{M^c}=(\operatorname{Int}M)^c$ holds.

> Theorem 7':
> Let $S$ be a non-empty set.
> Let $a:2^S\to2^S$ be a function which satisfies the following conditions:
> (1) $a(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.
> (2) $a(M)\supset M$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> (3) $a(M\cup N)=a(M)\cup a(N)$ for any $M,N\in 2^S$.
> (4) $a(a(M))=a(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> Then, there exists a unique topological space $(S,\mathcal{O})$ such that $\overline{M}=a(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.

The author wrote that the proof of Theorem 7' is easy if we use Theorem 7 and Lemma 1.

I proved Theorem 7' but I am not sure my proof is ok or not.

> My proof of Theorem 7':
> Assume that there exists a topological space $(S,\mathcal{O})$ such that $\overline{M}=a(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> Then, $\operatorname{Int}M=(\overline{M^c})^c=(a(M^c))^c$ holds for any $M\in 2^S$ by Lemma 1.
> Let $i(M):=(a(M^c))^c$.
> We prove that $i:2^S\to2^S$ satisfies the following conditions:
>
> (1) $i(S)=S$.
> (2) $i(M)\subset M$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> (3) $i(M\cap N)=i(M)\cap i(N)$ for any $M,N\in 2^S$.
> (4) $i(i(M))=i(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
>
> Proof of (1)
> $i(S)=(a(S^c))^c=a(\emptyset)^c=\emptyset^c=S$.
>
> Proof of (2)
> $a(M^c)\supset M^c$.
> So, $i(M)=(a(M^c))^c\subset (M^c)^c=M$.
>
> Proof of (3)
> $i(M\cap N)=(a((M\cap N)^c))^c=(a(M^c\cup N^c))^c=(a(M^c)\cup a(N^c))^c=(a(M^c))^c\cap (a(N^c))^c=i(M)\cap i(N).$
>
> Proof of (4)
> $i(M)=(a(M^c))^c.$
> $i(i(M))=(a((i(M))^c))^c=(a(a(M^c)))^c=(a(M^c))^c=i(M).$
>
> By Theorem 7, there exists a unique topological space $(S,\mathcal{O})$ such that $\operatorname{Int}M=i(M)=(a(M^c))^c$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> So, $\operatorname{Int}M^c=(a(M))^c$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> So, $(\operatorname{Int}M^c)^c=a(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> By Lemma 1, $(\operatorname{Int}M^c)^c=\overline{M}$.
> So, $\overline{M}=a(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$.
> This $(S,\mathcal{O})$ is the unique topologocal space such that $\overline{M}=a(M)$ for any $M\in 2^S$ by Lemma 1.

Comment: Seems correct. The topology is given by $\mathcal{O} = \lbrace O \in \mathcal{P}(S) | a(S \setminus O) = S \setminus O\rbrace$.

Comment: @Orb Thank you very much for your comment.